# synchronous function not working accordingly

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, jwt, passport.js

so, i was using passport-jwt and come on to this problem. i have two models that are Employee with name, address, role, ... and Employee credential with username, passsword , employee(Object_Id).
Then what i wanted is that after i found the employee username and password then i need the employee role so i used employee.findbyId but it returns a promise and call the callback done before getting role of the employee.

what i want is why it is happening(detail about it for understanding)??? i didn't use async/await so the function is synchronous.

```
 (passport)=>{
       let options = {};
       options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
       options.secretOrKey = config.SECRET;
       passport.use(new Strategy( options,(payload,done)=>{
           Employee_credential.findById(payload.data._id, (err, employee)=>{
                  if(err)  return done(err,false);
                  if(employee){ 
                var result = Employee.getById(employee.employee).populate('role').catch(err=>{throw err})
                          employee.role = result.role.role_Id;
                          return done(null, employee);
                              }
                  return done(null,false);
              })
       })) 
}
```

Comment: *i didn't use async/await so the function is synchronous* — it doesn't work that way. An API is asynchronous by its very nature, and whether you use `async` functions is up to you as a programmer.

Comment: async/await is what is known as *syntactic sugar* - it makes it easier to work with asynchronous functions, but it isn't what makes the function asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Things may be happening *sequentially* here, but not *synchronously*. Your functions are happening in the order as written, but it is not going to wait on the result of your API call. That is why you are getting a promise instead of the role of the employee. To make this work you should either use async/await (my preferred method) or return a promise and set up the next function with `.then`.

A note from personal experience, not all APIs are going to work properly with `await` depending on how they handle promises. In some cases, I've had to combine that with explicitly resolving the promise via `return new Promise((resolve) => { //your function; resolve(employee); }` or something like that.